# Is it possible to lazily fetch models in a Collection in Backbone.js, while sometimes fetching (and releasing) the whole collection?

Tags: javascript, ajax, collections, backbone.js

Here is my scenario:

I am using Backbone.js.

I have several large collections of data that I would rather not keep in memory at all time.  Therefore, a solution that involves keeping all my models in all of my collections in memory at all time is not good.

I need to be able to display and/or edit some selection of arbitrary records from these collections, and I need multiple views of the same model to point to the same record (so they will stay in sync).  So, it is better to pull these models from master collections, rather than do Model.fetches.

Now, it looks like I may be able to use Collection.fetch to pull these records on an as-needed basis, by using the ajax **data** setting in combination with the **{add: true}** option.  That would get me halfway to what I want, if it does the job.

The trouble is that at any given point in time, I may need to pull up a picker list view for one of these collections, and temporarily display *all* of the records for that particular collection (or, alternately, a paginated list, if it's *really* big).  I could fetch the whole collection (or a page of the collection) when I need to show them all -- great.  But, then, when I'm done with that picker view, I need to clear those extra records out.  How do I scrub them, without also losing track of my individual record models that I had fetched previously?

The best solution I have dreamed up, so far, is to keep an array of my ad-hoc records, and pass that to the collection, when I call reset to clean it up.  This would additionally require me to keep some kind of reference counts on those models, so I know when to drop them out of the collection.  That seems like a lot of book-keeping to me.  Is there a cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: If your main concern is the balance between _server requests_ and _memory usage_ you can move your already _fetched_ data to _localStorage_ so you don't need forward requests for this data. In other hand _are you sure your Models are removed in the `Collection.reset()` even if them have an extra reference?_ this looks weird to me.

Comment: I'm not sure how using localStorage really addresses the problem described in my question.  All it does is change where I'm populating the collection from. ???  As for your other question: If you call `Collection.reset()` with no arguments, it will _not_ result in the destruction of any models that have references in other views.  _However_, the next time I fetch that collection, it will fetch duplicate models for those records, and "change" events on the new models will not propagate to listeners on the old models, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

After read your last comment I think I understand you. So, trying to rewrite your question, what you have is:

- Models instantiate and assigned to *local variables*
- A *Collection* wich contains, among other Models, the ones you already have assigned to local variables

But the same Models in the *local variables* and in the *Collection* **are different instances** so changes in one reference doesn't affect to the other reference. And this is what you want to fix.

So, what we have to try is that the *references* in the local variables and in the Collection to be the same reference.

One approach can be that the Collection in the `initialize()` can check all its Models and replace the recent fetched ones for the already instantiate ones, if the `id` match, and if is not already there.

For do so we have some how to require the list of *already cached Models*. But this *already cached Models* are each one in a local variable into different Views or whatever, so we are gonna need an unique place where we could get the full list in a shot. This unique place can be a Collection called `CachedModels`.

In the `Model.initialize()` we can add a line that adds the current Model to this `CachedModels`. Also we have to take care to maintain this `CachedModels` collection clean up or removed Models.

This is not a very optimized, and not very easy, approach but I hope it can inspire you in any way.